# c# AForge.NET - how to save video from camera to file

Tags: c#, video, avi, aforge

I need some help with saving video from laptop camera to file. Now i use code to search video devices and previous video on pictureBox.
I've tried with AVIFileWrite but I failed. 
How to use VideoFileWriter to achive my goal??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using System.IO;
using AForge.Video.VFW;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace VideoCapture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo;
        public static Bitmap _latestFrame;
        //private VideoFileWriter writer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VideoCaptureDevices = new                  FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FinalVideo = new    VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
        FinalVideo.Start();
    }
    void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        pictureBox1.Image = video;

        //int width = 640;
        //int height = 480;

        //VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
        //writer.Open(@"c:\video.avi", width, height, 25, VideoCodec.Default, 1000000);

        //for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        //{
        //    writer.WriteVideoFrame(video);
        //}

        //writer.Close();

        //Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        //writer.WriteVideoFrame(image);                      
        //MessageBox.Show("jest");           
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
        {
            FinalVideo.Stop();

        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinalVideo.IsRunning == true) FinalVideo.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Device running..." + FinalVideo.FramesReceived.ToString() + " FPS";
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using AForge.Video.VFW;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;

        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo = null;
        private VideoCaptureDeviceForm captureDevice;
        private Bitmap video;
        //private AVIWriter AVIwriter = new AVIWriter();
        private VideoFileWriter FileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
        private SaveFileDialog saveAvi;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDeviceForm();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (captureDevice.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                //VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
                FinalVideo.Start();
            }
        }
        void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
            {
                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                //AVIwriter.Quality = 0;
                FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
                //AVIwriter.AddFrame(video);
            }
            else
            {
                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveAvi = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveAvi.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
            if (saveAvi.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int h = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;
                int w = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width;
                FileWriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h, 25, VideoCodec.Default, 5000000);
                FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);

                //AVIwriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h);
                butStop.Text = "Stop Record";
                //FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                //FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
                //FinalVideo.Start();
            }
        }

        private void butStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
            {
                butStop.Text = "Stop";
                if (FinalVideo == null)
                { return; }
                if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
                {
                    //this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                    FileWriter.Close();
                    //this.AVIwriter.Close();
                    pictureBox1.Image = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                FileWriter.Close();
                //this.AVIwriter.Close();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Save("IMG" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".jpg");
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalVideo == null)
            { return; }
            if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                FileWriter.Close();
                //this.AVIwriter.Close();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

in this way ;)

Comment: I'm using your code. It works!! but I have this problem: if I use laptop integrated webcam no problem. If I choose an external usb cam, image is black. Have you any idea?

Comment: You should set correct button names. It would be helpful

Comment: Really very helpful this example for me, Specially for code line [FileWriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h, 25, VideoCodec.Default, 5000000);].

Bitrate is very important when you want to record high definition video 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definite answer, but: everytime you call writer.Open(...) it uses Win32.OpenFileMode.Create instead of Win32.OpenFileMode.ReadWrite and so it will overwrite the file every time instead of adding frames, so your result will be a video containing 1 frame. I have the same problem: [my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659765/bitmaps-to-video-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Because a IPcamera doesn't have a steady framerate and the writer has no dynamic FPS, you can better use VLC.